# How can I manually deadletter a message.(The message is not send to the queue)

Tags: java, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, dead-letter

I need to deadletter a message when the API respose is not 200.
The message is not initially send to the main queue , I need to directly send the message to the deadletter.

Came accross deadLetter() method , but the argument should be of type 'ServiceBusReceiverClient' and manually converting to ServiceBusReceiverClient type is not possible since the constructors are private.
Is there any efficient way to directly deadletter a message through a Java application?
The queue is used to send other valid messages as well so making some configuration changes that applies to all messages cannot be implemented .

Comment: Can you share the code you have tried?

Comment: @DasariKamali I haven't written any code yet since I couldn't find a way to directly dead-letter a message without sending it to the queue first.

Comment: Found out that there is a method deadLetter(), that could send message to the deadletter ,  the argument type should be 'ServiceBusReceivedMessage' but manually converting message to ServiceBusReceivedMessage is not possible since the constructors are private.
The only way to achieve it as per my knowledge is to send the message to the queue and then receive the message from the queue so that the message will be of type ServiceBusReceivedMessage and then use the deadLetter() and send it to the deadLetter(which is a very clumsy method.

Comment: Can you share the code that fixes your issue? It will help other community.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, we can send the messages to the queue first and those messages will sent to the deadLetter queue.

**Code :**

```java
import com.azure.messaging.servicebus.*;
import com.azure.messaging.servicebus.models.*;

import java.util.List;

public class ServiceBus {

    private static final String SERVICE_BUS_CONNECTION_STRING = "<conec_string>";
    private static final String QUEUE_NAME = "<queue_name>";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        sendMessageToQueue();
        int responseCode = 404;
        if (responseCode != 200) {
            moveMessageToDeadLetterQueue();
        }
    }

    private static void sendMessageToQueue() {
        ServiceBusSenderClient sender = new ServiceBusClientBuilder()
                .connectionString(SERVICE_BUS_CONNECTION_STRING)
                .sender()
                .queueName(QUEUE_NAME)
                .buildClient();

        ServiceBusMessage message = new ServiceBusMessage("Hi Kamali");

        sender.sendMessage(message);
        System.out.println("Sent message to queue");

        sender.close();
    }
    private static void moveMessageToDeadLetterQueue() {
        ServiceBusReceiverClient receiver = new ServiceBusClientBuilder()
                .connectionString(SERVICE_BUS_CONNECTION_STRING)
                .receiver()
                .queueName(QUEUE_NAME)
                .buildClient();
        Iterable<ServiceBusReceivedMessage> receivedMessages = receiver.receiveMessages(1);

        for (ServiceBusReceivedMessage receivedMessage : receivedMessages) {
            receiver.deadLetter(receivedMessage);
            System.out.println("Moved message to dead-letter queue");
        }
        receiver.close();
    }
}
```

**Output :**

It ran successfully as below,

[image]

The message is sent to the main queue first as below,

[image]

And, quickly sent that message to the deadletter queue as below.

[image]